# iterate through dynamically generated table and access td values in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

The is my code in controller..

```
function get_grproduct(){
    $goodreceipt_id=$_POST['goodreceipt_id'];

    if($goodreceipt_id!=''){
        //$post_array['cart']='';
        $res = $this->db->query("select * from phppos_productdetails WHERE 
  goodreceipt_id='$goodreceipt_id'");
        ?>
        <tr>

            <th>Particulars</th>
            <th>Packing</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <!--<th>Action</th>-->

        </tr>
        <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach($res->result() as $row ){

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_name FROM phppos_product WHERE 
 product_id='".$row->product_id."'");
            foreach($query->result() as $row1 ){
                $product_name=$row1->product_name;

            }
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='width:40%;'>".$product_name."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:30%;' id='packing'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' id='quantity' style='width:80%;' readonly='' 
 value='".$row->quantity."'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:80%;' id='rate'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:100%;' id='amount' readonly=''/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;

        }


    }
}
```

On the id called rate I again called javascript function..code for that is as follows..

```
 $("#rate").live('blur', function(){

                var rate=$(this).val();
                var qty =$('#quantity').val();
                var amt=parseInt(rate)* parseInt(qty);

                $("#amount").val(amt);

            });
```

So my problem is it assigns amt variable value to amount id for only first record. So How do I use loop in bur function so I can assign each record it's amount and get total amount??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class instead of `id` as it must be unique.
Also use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) as [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) is not available in latest versions of jquery.
Now, your code looks like,

```
$("#cart_details").on('blur','.rate', function(){
     var rate=this.value;
     var $tr=$(this).closest('tr');
     var qty =$tr.find('.quantity').val(); // use quantity class not id
     var amt=parseInt(rate)* parseInt(qty);
     $tr.find(".amount").val(amt); // use amount class not id
});
```

And in your piece of PHP code would be,

```
.......
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='width:40%;'>".$product_name."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:30%;' id='packing'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:80%;' readonly=''  value='".$row->quantity."'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:80%;' class='rate'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:100%;' class='amount' readonly=''/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
.......
```

Comment: I change your code according to my need but it assign same amt to each record.

Comment: Can you show an online demo, or have you any URL which I can see.

Comment: sry..I cant..But I can show you my changed code..see my edit above

Comment: You are using live() in a wrong way, us ON() instead. Also, see in your browser console for any errors. Use `$("#cart_details").on('blur','.rate', function(){` not `$("#cart_details").live('blur','.rate', function(){` AND use `var rate=$(this).val();` not `var rate=$('.rate').val();`. And `var tr=$(this).closest('tr');` *First try my code as it is*

Comment: I know live is deprecated but if I use on event then everything stop working. I include jquery 1.11.2.min.js file.

Comment: Any errors in console? **Remember live is not available in jquery 1.11**. *You must need to use on()* Also wrap your code in document.ready()

Comment: when I use your code. in console error is .on is not function.

Comment: May be you are using one or more jquery versions (See your page source) use jquery.noConflict() if it needed, otherwise remove the older version

Comment: If I remove old version..evething stops working..So I have to manage with .live event. So tell me about that.

Comment: You can use  delegate function http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ like,$("#cart_details").delegate('.rate','blur', function(){